# Why is osm road data showing up with lines radiating from a point?

Tags: openstreetmap, tilemill

My openstreetmap data has artifacts that I can't seem to get rid of. It is showing the roads underneath the artifacts so I know that the query is working at least partially.

The data is from geofabrik.de for the D.R./Haiti region, downloaded via the .bz2 file into a PostgreSQL database as per the instructions here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql.

I'm displaying it in TileMill via the query: ( SELECT * FROM planet_osm_line
        WHERE "highway" IN ('motorway','trunk')
        ORDER BY z_order asc ) AS route

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using a osm2pgsql version that is able to handle 64-bit-IDs, and the PostgreSQL and Postgis version it is build against? There are some strange errors in OSM data handling since the node IDs have cracked the 32-bit limit.

You could try the older CC-BY-SA Version from `http://download.geofabrik.de/osm-before-redaction/central-america/haiti-and-domrep.osm.pbf`, but you have to translate that to .osm format with osmconvert before feeding the data to the Postgis database.